# Strange Primefaces4 update issue

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using PF4, the following occurs with this version (with 3.5 everything is fine):

Here are two `p:remoteCommand`s

```
<p:remoteCommand name="refreshUserList" actionListener="#{userListManagedBean.loadUserList}" update="usersTabView:usersDataTableContainer"/>
```

and

```
<p:remoteCommand name="refreshInactiveUserList" actionListener="#{inactiveUserListManagedBean.loadUserList}" update="usersTabView:inactiveUsersDataTableContainer"/>
```

The problem: If I make a user inactive then it call the `refreshInactiveUserList` remoteCommand and everything is fine, but if I make a user active, it calls the `refreshUserList` remoteCommand, the function in the bean successfully executes, but in the ajax response the userDataTable doesn't contain the new active user.

Any idea is welcome!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `process="@this"` on `p:remoteCommand`.
And also its a good idea to keep `p:remoteCommand` in a separate `h:form`.